# How count table a data for every data of table a

Tags: laravel, model, controller, laravel-5.6

I have three table `A`,`B`,`C`.

**A** table:

> id,name

**B** table:

> id,a_id,date

**C** table:

> id,b_id,type(value is 0/1)

I want to print all A.name,A.id and C.countingdata by counting C data where C.type=1 using B table which has A table id

Result look like below:

```
A.id   A.name       C.countingdata
1      abc          4
2      vfd          2
3      fdg          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Well, you can first inner join `B` and `C`, do the `group by` and get `C.countingdata` using `count()`. Another join on this subquery with `B` itself to accommodate the `a_id` 
  in the result set.
- Now, you can do an inner join between `A` and the above subquery to get your results.

**SQL:**

```
select A.id, A.name, derived.countingData
from A
inner join (
                select B.id as b_id,B.a_id,sub_data.countingData
                from B 
                inner join (
                                select B.id,count(B.id) as countingData
                                from B 
                                inner join C
                                on B.id = C.b_id
                                where C.type=1
                                group by B.id
                            ) sub_data
                on B.id = sub_data.id
            ) derived
on A.id = derived.a_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find query as below:

```
Select 
    A.id
    ,A.name
    ,COUNT(C.id)
    FROM A 
    JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
    JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id ANd C.type = 1
    GROUP BY 
    A.id
    ,A.name
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you did a little better